# How to replace the current navigationStack with a new one?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

- Currently, when I open the app for the first time, the tryLocalSignin() method in the useEffect of Signin.js file checks for saved token in AsyncStorage, if available, signs in.
- Once signed in, the user should not be able to go back to the signin screen unless he signs out but can do anyways right now.
- **What I want to accomplish now is I want to update navigation stack so that once the user signs in, he cannot go back to the signin screen unless the user signs out of the app.**
- How do I do that from my AuthContext.js file?

> //Main App.js file

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator  } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import AccountScreen from './src/screens/AccountScreen';
import AddProductScreen from './src/screens/AddProductScreen';
import ListProductScreen from './src/screens/ListProductsScreen';
import SigninScreen from './src/screens/SigninScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';
import { navigationRef } from './src/RootNavigation';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Tabs() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Add Product" component={AddProductScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="List Product" component={ListProductScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  )
}

function Auth() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Signin" component={SigninScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="BIB Store" component={Auth} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

> Signin Screen

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Text, Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements'
import Spacer from '../components/Spacer'
import { Context as AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'

const SigninScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state, signin, clearErrorMessage, tryLocalSignin } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('test1@test.com')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('password')
    useEffect(() => {
        tryLocalSignin()
        navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            clearErrorMessage()
          });
    }, [])
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Spacer>
                <Spacer>
                    <Text h2>Hello User. Login to BIB Store!</Text>
                </Spacer>
                <Spacer>
                    <Input 
                        label="Email" 
                        value={email}
                        onChangeText={setEmail}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        placeholder="shopper@bibstore.com"
                    />
                    <Input 
                        label="Password" 
                        value={password}
                        onChangeText={setPassword}
                        // secureTextEntry
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCorrect={false}

                    />
                    { state.errorMessage ? 
                        <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{state.errorMessage}</Text>
                        : null 
                    }
                </Spacer>
                <Spacer>
                    <Button 
                        title="Signin" 
                        onPress={() => signin({ email, password })}
                    />
                </Spacer>
                <Spacer>
                    <Text 
                        style={styles.authLink}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
                            New User? Click here to Register!
                </Text>
                </Spacer>  
            </Spacer>
        </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        // borderColor: 'red',
        // borderWidth: 10,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginBottom: '10%',

    },
    errorMessage: {
        fontSize: 30,
        color: 'red',
        textAlign: 'center',
        // marginTop: -20
    },
    authLink: {
        fontSize: 30,
        color: 'black',
        textAlign: 'center',
        textDecorationLine: 'underline'
    }
})


export default SigninScreen
```

> RootNavigation.js for navigation without navigation props

```
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

> AuthContext.js (Actions/Reducer file)

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';


import bibstoreApi from "../api/bibstore";
import * as RootNavigation from '../RootNavigation';

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add_error':
            return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
        case 'signin':
            return { errorMessage: '', token: action.payload };
        case 'clear_error_message':
            return { ...state, errorMessage: ''}
        case 'signout':
            return { token: null, errorMessage:'' }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const clearErrorMessage = dispatch => () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'clear_error_message' })
}

const tryLocalSignin = dispatch => async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
    if(token) {
        dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: token })
        RootNavigation.navigate('Tabs');
    } else {
        RootNavigation.navigate('Signin'); 
    }
}

const signup = (dispatch) => async ({ email, name, phone, password }) => {
        try {
            const response = await bibstoreApi.post('/signup', { email, name, phone, password });
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@token', response.data.token);
            dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: response.data.token})
            console.log(response.data);

            // navigate to main flow
        } catch (err) {
            // console.log(err.response.data.error);
            dispatch({ type: 'add_error', payload: err.response.data.error})
        }
};

const signin = dispatch => async ({ email, password }) => {
        try {
            const response = await bibstoreApi.post('/signin', { email, password });
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@token', response.data.token);
            dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: response.data.token})
            console.log('TOKEN --> ',response.data.token);

            // navigate to main 
            // RootNavigation.navigate('Tabs', { screen: 'Add Product' });
            RootNavigation.navigate('Tabs');

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response.data);
            dispatch({ type: 'add_error', payload: 'Invalid email or password'})
        }
};

const signout = (dispatch) => async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@token')
    dispatch({ type: 'signout' })
    RootNavigation.navigate('Signin')
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
    authReducer,
    { signin, signout, signup, clearErrorMessage, tryLocalSignin },
    { token: null, errorMessage: '' }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do. Per the [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) on authentication flows you should split your current `Auth` and `Tab` stack into two different stacks, something like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  // determine your 'logged-in' state here from somewhere
  const isLoggedIn = value;

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          {isSignedIn ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="BIB Store"
                component={Auth}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Tabs"
                component={Tabs}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Now when your `isLoggedIn` value changes, the user is automatically navigated to the auth or tab stack.

Comment: Tried doing this but does not work.
I am calling the isSignedIn method from inside of App function, but getting error.
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: `const isSignedIn = async () => {
  const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(state)
}`

Comment: If you are using context, have you added a provider? Hooks are also not ment to be called in functions, just use them in your component.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how exactly to do it? I am new to this. I was following a video but this issue was not addressed.

Comment: There is an example provided in the docs I linked.

Comment: I think I am almost there. I user AsyncStorage to save my token and I am fetching that token in App.js file. But in the App.js function, the return statement is getting called before async finishes because of  async's typical behaviour.

Comment: `let loggedIn
const isSignedIn = async () => {
  loggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
}
export default function App() {
  isSignedIn()
  console.log(loggedIn)
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          { loggedIn==null ? 
              (<Stack.Screen name="BIB Store" component={Auth}/>)
              :
              (<Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs}/>)
          }
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}`